# Python-Create array from txt

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm trying to create an array of stock tickers in Python 2.7 from a txt file. The txt file simply has 1 ticker per line like:

```
SRCE
ABTX
AMBC
ATAX
```

The code I'm using looks like:

```
FinTick= []

    def parseRus():
        try:
        readFile=open(r'filename.txt','r').read()
        splitFile=readFile.split('\n')
        FinTick.append(splitFile)
        print FinTick



        except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

When I call 'parseRus()' I get an output that looks like:

```
'\xff\xfeS\x00R\x00C\x00E\x00\r\x00', '\x00A\x00B\x00T\x00X\x00\r\x00', '\x00A\x00M\x00B\x00C\x00\r\x00', '\x00A\x00T\x00A\x00X\x00\r\x00'
```

The correct letters are present but not printing in plane text. I've used a couple other logic methods to populate the array but still get the same output format.

Comment: Have a look at [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). This should work better than plain opening and reading.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `r` from your `r'filename.txt'`open?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I get an invalid mode or filename error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> tickers = []
>>> with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
        for ticker in f.readlines():
            tickers.append(ticker.strip())


>>> tickers
['SRCE', 'ABTX', 'AMBC', 'ATAX']
```

Try using `readlines()` and `strip()` instead.

Edit: Some clarity around `f.readlines()` and `strip()`:

```
>>> with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.readlines())

['SRCE\n', 'ABTX\n', 'AMBC\n', 'ATAX']
```

So, when we're iterating through the `list` object returned by `f.readlines()`, we will need to strip the newline `\n` characters. Use the `strip()` method for `str` types to do this.

Edit 2: @Eli is right. We can just use `for ticker in f` instead of `for ticker in f.readlines()`, too.

```
>>> tickers = []
>>> with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
        for ticker in f:
            tickers.append(ticker.strip())

>>> tickers
['SRCE', 'ABTX', 'AMBC', 'ATAX']
```

Comment: No need to use `readlines`. Just do `for ticker in f:`. There is no need to read the entire file into RAM.

Comment: I'm not clear you've solved their issue, can you replicate the OP's current output?

Comment: OP's code actually works for me. I get the same result from their code as I do with my code. I just wonder if there are extraneous characters in their text file.

Comment: @Eli Korvigo I'm still getting the output in the same format. Could it have something to do with the 'r' preceding the 'filename.txt' input? I'm not sure why I'm getting the 'invalid mode or filename' error if I don't put the 'r' first.

Comment: Any ideas on why you get the right output and my output is formatted in such an odd fashion?

Comment: I would check and make sure your `filename.txt` file has no extraneous characters in it, and literally just contains ticker values on each line.

Comment: Figured out a fix and posted below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured a fix.

I had to modify the text file from 1 column to 1 row then saved as a .csv and modified the code to:

```
FinTick= []

def parseRus():
    try:
        readFile=open(r'filename.csv','r').read()
        splitFile=readFile.split(',')
        for eachLine in splitFile:
            splitLine=eachLine.split(',')
            ticker=splitLine[0]
            FinTick.append(ticker.strip())



    except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```